# Print HTML Table with Multiple Table Header

Tags: html, html-table

Please help me, on How to Print HTML Table with Multiple Table Header? 
Sample code of my table header below:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">January 2018</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">TARGET</th>
            <th colspan="2">ORDERED</th>
            <th colspan="2">SALES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>QTY</th> <th>AMOUNT</th>
            <th>QTY</th> <th>AMOUNT</th>

            <th>QTY</th> <th>AMOUNT</th>
            <th>QTY</th> <th>AMOUNT</th>

            <th>QTY</th> <th>AMOUNT</th>
            <th>QTY</th> <th>AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what i want to see in printable page for the Table Header:

[image]

Comment: I have already a JavaScript function to print the table, but it doesn't include the headers when printing. That's my only problem right now. Thank you very for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table border="2" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th colspan="6" ></th>
        <th colspan="6">January 2018</th> 
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th colspan="6"></th>
        <th colspan="2">TARGET</th>
        <th colspan="2">ORDERED</th>
        <th colspan="2">SALES</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th  colspan="2">item</th>
        <th colspan="6">Description</th>
        <th colspan="1">QTY</th> <th colspan="1">AMOUNT</th>
        <th colspan="1">QTY</th> <th colspan="1">AMOUNT</th>
        <th colspan="1">QTY</th> <th colspan="1">AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

</tbody>
```

Comment: More coded for you! Just, increase or decrease colspan according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

See below code..

```
<table border="2" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6" ></th>
        <th colspan="6">January 2018</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6"></th>
        <th colspan="2">TARGET</th>
        <th colspan="2">ORDERED</th>
        <th colspan="2">SALES</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th  colspan="2">item</th>
        <th colspan="4">Description</th>
        <th colspan="1">QTY</th> <th colspan="1">AMOUNT</th>
        <th colspan="1">QTY</th> <th colspan="1">AMOUNT</th>
        <th colspan="1">QTY</th> <th colspan="1">AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

</tbody>
```

here is working example :: https://jsfiddle.net/deepakvaishnav/0L48mvcz/